# Determine if $_SESSION superglobal exists in PHP

Tags: php, session

I want to do something like this:

```
if ($_SESSION['errors'] exists)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

I want to create a session on page1 and then go to page2 where it will check for errors, if there are errors it returns to page1 with the errors.

But page1 will give errors if the variable hasn't been created yet on page 2.

If I do `$_SESSION['errors'] == ""` on page1 it will reset the variable so that's no good.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

```
if (isset($_SESSION['errors']))
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

Comment: .. xD That's ... a lot easier than I'd thought, thanks man it works. Sorry I'm new to php and I'm just learning stuff as I go so ^^ I'll mark it as solved as soon as I can

Answer (score 10):

use `isset()` and `empty()` php function.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['errors']) && !empty($_SESSION['errors'])) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['id']) || (trim($_SESSION['id']) == '')) {
     // do stuff
}
```